# Como fazer um LINQ/lambda e consumi-lo na view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, razor

Tenho um objeto chamado `Radio`:

```
public class Radio
{
    public int RadioId { get; set; }
    public string StreamUrl { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }
    public bool Mp3 { get; set; }
}
```

Estou fazendo um select no *controller* e tentando envia-la para a *View*:

```
    var RadioAtivo = db.Radios
        .Where(p => p.Ativo == true && p.Mp3 == false)
        .Take(1);

return View(RadioAtivo.ToList());
```

Na *view*, gostaria de recuperar, por exemplo, o campo `StreamURL`

```
@model List<RadioFM.Domain.Domain.Radio>

<p>@Html.DisplayFor(r => r.???) </p>
```

Pensei em colocar em uma `ViewBag`, mas achei meio gambiarra. Pensei em criar uma `ViewModel` já com os dados, mas achei que seria meio que duplicar um problema.

**Qual a solução mais simples nesse caso?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mais simples é a que você está fazendo mesmo. Outras formar como a [`ViewBag`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ou criar uma *view model* podem ser úteis em certas situações, mas são mais complexas e portanto só devem ser usadas se o código exigir seu uso para alcançar o resultado.

Não me parece que você esteja precisando de uma forma dinâmica para passar o objeto, que é a função da `ViewBag`. Nem precisa de um intermediário onde precisa fazer alguma coisa extra ou organizar melhor o dado para ser usado na *view*:

```
<p>@Html.DisplayFor(r => r.StreamUrl) </p>
```

Eu mudaria a expressão de consulta para tirar a redundância e talvez mudaria o modelo para entregar um item como deseja (conforme comentários):

```
var RadioAtivo = db.Radios
    .Where(p => p.Ativo && !p.Mp3)
    .Take(1);
return View(RadioAtivo.ToList()[0]);
```

Ou melhor ainda:

```
var RadioAtivo = db.Radios
    .Where(p => p.Ativo && !p.Mp3)
    .First();
return View(RadioAtivo.ToList());
```

Como vai receber apenas um item não receberá uma lista, então mude:

```
@model RadioFM.Domain.Domain.Radio
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/LinqInView.cs).

E confirmo o que eu disse nos comentários, repense este `RadioFM.Domain.Domain.Radio`, isto não parece ser necessário.

Comment: Da um erro, falando que StreamUrl não faz parte System.Collections.Generic.List<RadioFM.Domain.Domain.Radio>' e inclusive o intellissense não funciona

Comment: Você tem certeza que o tipo é este mesmo? `RadioFM.Domain.Domain.Radio`, quando voc~e digita o `r.` quais propriedades aparecem?

Comment: é o caminho da minha classe Radio, não seria isso? será o List<> o problema?

Comment: Não sei, cada um faz de um jeito. Eu achei o tipo muito confuso, mas pode ser por necessidade sua. Não tinha me tocado do `List`. Você quer apresentar um rádio ou uma lista de rádios? Se quer uma lista, precisa acrescentar um `@foreach` na *view* para percorrer a lista. Se quer só um, precisará enviar um item e não uma lista. Pelo que entendi  que apenas um, e se for isto, talvez seja interessante mudar o *controller* para entregar um item e não uma lista. Ainda pode pegar apenas um na *view* selecionando o primeiro item.Talvez uma `ViewBag` seja interessante para organizar, mas não necessária

Comment: somente um item...eu coloquei o list na view pq sem ele da o erro The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RadioFM.Domain.Domain.Radio]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'RadioFM.Domain.Domain.Radio'.

Comment: Fez o que eu falei acima? Eu editei a resposta. Eu não conheço muito bem as peculiaridades (as "mágicas" internas) do ASP.Net MVC mas tem algumas coisas que não fogem da lógica, se você quer um item, mande um item, aí não tem erro. Não trabalha mais com uma lista. Note que eu disse que você não precisa solucionar isto com `ViewBag` ou um *view model*, mas pode fazer isto se preferir. Se for mais fácil para você, se entende como fazer isto para resolver.

Answer (score 5):

Isto aqui não faz sentido:

```
var RadioAtivo = db.Radios
    .Where(p => p.Ativo == true && p.Mp3 == false)
    .Take(1);

return View(RadioAtivo.ToList());
```

Se você quer apresentar apenas um elemento em tela, em primeiro lugar, você não precisar usar `Where()` com o `Take()`. Não que não funcione, mas isso devolve uma lista, e o que você quer é apenas um elemento.

Você deve usar `First()` ou `Single()` (se tem certeza de que o elemento existe) ou então `FirstOrDefault()` se não tem essa certeza (os dois primeiros dão erro se não existir o elemento):

```
var RadioAtivo = db.Radios
    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Ativo == true && p.Mp3 == false);
```

O objeto passado para o `return`, portanto, é apenas um elemento que não precisa ser convertido para `ToList()`:

```
return View(RadioAtivo);
```

A *View*, por sua vez, não trabalha com uma lista, então não faz sentido você usar isso aqui:

```
@model List<RadioFM.Domain.Domain.Radio>
```

`@model` serve para você dizer para a *View* o que será colocado dentro da variável `Model` (nesta grafia, em maiúsculo). O correto é apenas a declaração de classe, conforme abaixo:

```
@model RadioFM.Domain.Domain.Radio
```

(uma observação: este nome de *namespace* `RadioFM.Domain.Domain.Radio` tem tudo para ser um anti-padrão e, portanto, uma má prática)

Assim sendo, a `StreamUrl` pode ser exibida assim:

```
<p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.StreamUrl)</p>
```

Ou ainda simplesmente assim, se não houver formatação configurada no projeto:

```
<p>@Model.StreamUrl</p>
```

Comment: perfeito, agradeço a atenção como sempre, é um projeto pra mim mesmo, sem objetivos comerciais, apenas para aprendizado do MVC.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, por que  `RadioFM.Domain.Domain.Radio` seria um anti-padrao? fiquei curioso.

Comment: @TobyMosque Se você tem uma *Class Library* chamada `RadioFM.Domain`, por que precisa ter um diretório `Domain` dentro dela? Essa *Class Library* guarda alguma outra coisa que não seja o `Domain`?